# constructing skip-gram input vector

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, word2vec

I am following the tutorial [here](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/04/21/the-amazing-power-of-word-vectors/) for implementing word2vec, and I am not sure if I understand how the skip-gram input vector is constructed.

[image]

This is the part I am confused about. I thought we were not doing one-hot encoding in word2vec.

For example, if we were to have two sentences "dogs like cats", "cats like dogs", or some more informative sentences, what would the input vector look like? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What Skip-gram tries to do is essentially to train a model that predicts its context words given the center word.

Take 'dogs like cats' as example, assuming that window size is three, which means we will use the center word("like") to predict one word before "like" and one word after "like"(correct answers here are "dogs" and "cats").
So the input vector for this sentence will be an one hot vector with kth element being one(assuming "like" is the kth word in your dictionary).